# How to pass observable to parent component in angularjs2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

I've got two components, SearchComponent and RuleListComponent.
Search is children of RuleList.

[image]

I want SearchComponent to use APIService to download data.
This data have to be passed to RuleList in observable.

SearchComponent:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Observable<Array<string>>;
  term = new FormControl(); # term is async

  constructor(private apiService: APIService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.term.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.apiService.fetch('rule', term));
  }
}
```

APIService:

```
@Injectable()
export class APIService {
  baseUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.baseUrl = '//127.0.0.1:8000/';
  }

  fetch(term: string) : Observable<any> {
    console.log('searching');
    var search = new URLSearchParams();
    search.set('search', term);
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, { search })
                    .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

How can I keep passing data from SearchComponent to RuleListComponent asynchronously depending on changing term?

Comment: store the `items` on the `APIService` so your `SearchComponent` and `RuleListComponent` have access to them

Answer (score 2):

A good idea would be to make a `SearchService` and have both `RuleListComponent` and `SearchComponent` inject this service.

Then have `SearchService` inject the `ApiService` and set the items inside the `SearchService` and not in your component. Components should not be used for storing data